# A query on sending multiple requests using Axios - React

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

There is a scenario where I need to call multiple services at once using Axios and I need to consider values for success API calls and neglect the failed API calls. For example, see the case below:

```
let URL1 = "https://www.something.com"
let URL2 = "https://www.something1.com"
let URL3 = "https://www.something2.com"

const promise1 = axios.get(URL1);  // SUCCESS
const promise2 = axios.get(URL2);  // SAY THIS SERVICE CALL WAS FAILED SENDING 404 ERROR
const promise3 = axios.get(URL3);  // SUCCESS

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
}).catch((e)=>{ console.log("error",e)});
```

Say the Service 2 was failed while service 1 and 3 are succeeded, in such case the promise chain getting broken and throwing the error. I gonna need the output in such case as `[response_1 , null, response_3]`. Can you please guide me in how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you should **manually implement it** by returning `Promise.resolve()` on **catch**.

```
let URL1 = "https://www.something.com"
let URL2 = "https://www.something1.com"
let URL3 = "https://www.something2.com"

const promise1 = axios.get(URL1).catch(() => Promise.resolve());  // SUCCESS
const promise2 = axios.get(URL2).catch(() => Promise.resolve());  // SAY THIS SERVICE CALL WAS FAILED SENDING 404 ERROR
const promise3 = axios.get(URL3).catch(() => Promise.resolve());  // SUCCESS

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
}).catch((e)=>{ console.log("error",e)});
```

This way, if an axios request fail, it will **first get in axios.catch** then return a **success** with whatever value you need.

You can find more informations about **Promise chaining** on [MDN Using Promises Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining) (*like chaining after a catch*).

`Promise.all()` will not see any catch, so keep in mind those request **will no longer be able to fail** on `Promise.all`.